# Mysqli и пространство имен

Tags: php

есть файл a.php

```
namespace Models\test;   
use Mysqli;
    abstract class a{
      public static function test(){
       $a = new Mysqli(...);
      }
    }
```

При использовании (вызываю в другом файле данную функцию вот так - `static::test()`) получаю ошибку вида

```
Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002)
```

Гуглил, но так и не нашел внятного ответа. Как исправить ?

Comment: гуглить потому что надо код ошибки, а не то что вы гуглили

Comment: @teran А вы знаете, что я гуглил ? Тогда вам нужно в соответствующую передачу идти. К слову, проблему решил. Забыл, что для localhost/127... стоял алиас.

Comment: с учетом того что в заголовке вопроса указано "mysqli и пространства имен", то явно гуглили вы не проблемы с подключением

Comment: @teran гуглил код ошибки. Получал бодягу с сокетами. Ладно уж, проблема решена и хорошо

Comment: Если проблема решена - стоит дать на нее ответ, тем самым помочь другим вопрошающим.